# Unable to locate a span class by python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a span class attribute which I need to click and pass value to it.

Below is my span class:

```
<span class="input-group-addon-transparent icon-search sysparm-search-icon"></span>
```

Please do help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: <span class="input-group-addon-transparent icon-search sysparm-search-icon"></span>

Comment: Please add some code work by you to reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the full HTML of the site you can get the first span which matches those classes by using `find_element_by_css_selector`:

```py
selector = "span.input-group-addon-transparent.icon-search.sysparm-search-icon"
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
element.click()
element.sendKeys("value")
```

Or waiting for clickable state:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

selector = "span.input-group-addon-transparent.icon-search.sysparm-search-icon"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
element.sendKeys("value")
```

Where `driver` is your Selenium webdriver object

Answer (score 1):

You case use class name to get that webelement.

```
 webele=  driver.find_element_by_class_name("input-group-addon-transparent icon-search sysparm-search-icon")
webele.click();
webele.sendkeys("any string/number")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'search-icon')]
```

//and then rest of the code

Use web driver wait before clicking on button

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "XPATH"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the xpath of the span using any browser console then try using this code below to click and pass the value to it

```
span = find_element_by_xpath('''the x_path of the class''').click()
span.sendKeys('''value to be passed''')
```